Why Kendo menu is showing overlapping text?
I have a simple app where a  Kendo menu is displayed and there is some text content on the page. The problem is that when the menu shows up then it still shows the text content behind it as in the image below.

The sample for this including all code can be seen at Demo code for this issue. The code in this sample has been divided into three sections using the following comments <!--page resources-->, <!--page script-->, <!--page html--> and <!--page styles-->
The correct display for Kendo menu should be as below.

What I found after some research is that if the style of the paragraph displaying the text content has position:unset, then this Kendo menu issue disappears, but I still fail to understand why by adding this style the text content gets hidden behind the Kendo menu? The text content is still at the same position as it was when the issue was there, yet it's now hidden below the menu.

The sidebar does not have z-index set so the article content is shown above the menu. You can fix it by adding the below z-index style.
#sidebar {
    background: transparent;
    overflow: visible;
    z-index:1;
}

Demo

Thank you for the answer. You did point to the root of the problem that I was not seeing. But, could you please also explain why by only unsetting the position of the text content, the issue got resolved, even though the text content is still at the same position in the page.

@Sunil My understanding is from top to bottom items are stacked, so the article is stacked on top of navbar, hence you are getting the problem, but we can easily override this by explicitely mentioning the z-index for the nav, this is my understanding of the problem, I may be wrong!

you're correct because that's the root cause. But still, if I only unset the position of the text content without adding any z-index to the sidebar, the menu gets stacked on top of the text content, which I am failing to understand. It seems that if the position is static then it gets stacked to the bottom, but not sure.

@Sunil WHen position is static, zindex is not applied, I saw the warning on chrome debugger

ok. I saw something interesting in Google search that may be the reason why unsetting position also resolves the issue. To change the stacking order, you can add the position property. Positioned elements have a position value relative, absolute, sticky, or fixed. Positioned elements are displayed in front of any non-positioned elements..

When both the text content and the menu item are positioned, then the text content is appearing on top since it was rendered after the menu element. But when the text content position is unset, then the positioned menu item appears on top since that's the rule in stacking of html elements i.e. unpositioned elements are stacked below the positioned items . This is what appears to me based on the online search I just did.
